# Creating barcodes in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am using barcode font to generate barcodes,

```
column A text - *column B Barcode*
```

I have the following macro in ThisWorkbook which works okay.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If IsEmpty(Target) Or Target.Column <> 1 And Target.Column <> 4 Then Exit Sub

    Dim DataRow As Integer

    DataRow = Target.Cells.Row

    While Not IsEmpty(Cells(DataRow, Target.Column))

        Target.Worksheet.Cells(DataRow, Target.Column + 1) = "*" & Target.Worksheet.Cells(DataRow, Target.Column) & "*"

        DataRow = DataRow + 1

    Wend

End Sub
```

when I scan 22 digit # in column A; on column B would like to skip the first 7 digit and have the last 15 digit on column B

```
e.g:
If 22 digit skip first 7 
If 32 digit skip first 16 & last 4 
If 34 digit skip first 22
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the *sh* parameter of the `Workbook_SheetChange` event macro is the worksheet object containing *Target*. You can use it directly; there is no need to pare the worksheet from *Target*.

Next, it is always a good idea when adding/modifying/deleting objects within a `Worksheet_Change` or `Workbook_SheetChange` event macro to turn off `application.enableevents` so the macro does not try to run on top of itself when it changes/deleted/adds a value on the same (or different) worksheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Sh.Range("A:A, D:D"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Fìn
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim DataRow As Long, rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Sh.Range("A:A, D:D"), Target)
            Select Case Len(rng.Value2)
                Case 0
                    'do nothing
                Case 22
                    rng.Offset(0, 1) = Chr(42) & Mid(rng.Value2, 8, 99) & Chr(42)
                Case 32
                    rng.Offset(0, 1) = Chr(42) & Mid(rng.Value2, 8, 21) & Chr(42)
                Case 34
                    rng.Offset(0, 1) = Chr(42) & Mid(rng.Value2, 23, 99) & Chr(42)
                Case Else
                    rng.Offset(0, 1) = Chr(42) & rng.Value2 & Chr(42)
            End Select
        Next rng
    End If

Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

*Target* knows which worksheet it is on so there is really no need to define the worksheet when referencing a cell offset to *Target*.

A `Select Case` ... End Select` based on the length of the values in *Target* seemed the best solution and allows for easy expandability.

And finally, do you really need this for multiple worksheets as a `Workbook_SheetChange` event macro or would a single worksheet's `Worksheet_Change` suffice?

Comment: I need it only for Single Worksheet, Thanks @Jeeped

Comment: @Omar - This shouldn't be tough to convert to a `Worksheet_Change`. If you have trouble, post back. If you use this as-is, you should compare `sh.Name` or `sh.CodeName` to a list of known worksheet names that you want to process and exclude others.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake on 32 digit I wana skip first 16 & last 4

Comment: @Omar - Skipping the first 16 would mean you start at the 17th character. If you also want to omit the last 4, you would want the next 12 characters. See the VBA [Mid function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for information on where these two numbers should go.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim tmp,v
    Dim c As Range

    On Error Goto haveError
    For Each c in Target.Cells
        tmp=trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 And (c.Column=1 Or c.Column=4) Then

            Select Case Len(tmp)
                Case 22: v = Right(tmp, Len(tmp)-7)
                Case 32: 'etc
                Case 34: 'etc
                Case Else: v=""
            End Select

            If Len(v)>0 Then 
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                c.offset(0,1).value = "*" & v & "*"
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    Exit sub

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```